# jquery set function to react on every dynamically added input id and get this input id number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically add more input fields where orders id goes like this, orders1, orders2, orders3, etc.:

```
html_code += '<input type="text" name="orders[]" id="orders'+count+'">';
```

now I have this code:

```
$('#orders1 / 2 3').typeahead({ **//here I need to set to javascript react on all numbers dynamically**
 //mycode ...
 ordernumber = 1 / 2 3...; **//here I need to extract number**
 updater: function (obj) {
            var item = JSON.parse(obj);
            $('#orderitem' + ordernumber).val(item.tax);
            return item.name;
        }
});
```

1. how should I set `$('#orders1 / 2 3')` to be able to react on every dynamically added input?
2. how can I get `ordernumber` to be able to set it up on line $('#orderitem' + ordernumber)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option would be to add a class to all dynamic inputs and to get `ordernumber` set a `data-*` custom attribute like:

```
html_code += '<input class="orders" data-number="'+ count +'" name="orders[]" id="orders'+count+'">';
```

and then you can apply `typeahead` to all of them like:

```
$('.orders').each(function() {

  //here extract number
  var ordernumber = $(this).data('number');

  // here initialise typeahead
  $(this).typeahead({
    ....
  });
});
```

---

**Edit:**

Put this logic in a function like:

```
function reInit(){
    $('.orders').each(function() {

      //here extract number
      var ordernumber = $(this).data('number');

      // here initialise typeahead
      $(this).typeahead({
        ....
      });
    });
}

// Call the function initially
reInit();
```

and adding the elements dynamically and appending it to the dom call the function again.

```
html_code += '<input class="orders" data-number="'+ count +'" name="orders[]" id="orders'+count+'">';

// I don't know how are you adding the item to dom
// but something like
$(parent).append( html_code )

// Now call the function again
reInit();
```

Comment: it works on input directly in html file but when I append new textarea with $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code); function is not called on that textarea field. Any idea why?

Comment: This happens because `$('.orders')` only look for elements present in the DOM atm. For the new elements you will need to call this again. Maybe put this each logic inside a function lets say `reinit()` and everytime you add a new element to the dom, just call `reinit()` after that

Comment: could you please give me an example? I am just newbie with javascript. But I really appreciate your help :) thank you for it!

Comment: I have added some logic. But that is the most I can help. Hope you can figure out the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Oh perfect. I got it! I found solution to move it to function exactly at the same time as you. Many many thanks!